# PUG and line breaks

Tags: css, pug, html-templates

I know this has been asked about 20 times by now..
Somehow, i cant get any combination of old answers to work...

I just want to have linebreaks in my text...

```
p Pahoittelemme, tapahtui tekninen virhe, josta automaattinen palautuminen ei ollut mahdollista
br
p voit ilmoita virheestä xxxx, tai yritä hetken kuluttua uudestaan.
br
p Kiitos.
```

I've tried with looots of combinations of pipes, p tags, br tags and even straight up CSS. none have actually added line breaks.

```
p text
| more text
br even more text
| does the text ever stop??
```

This kinda works but then just the first 'text' is actually inside `<p>` tags

please help me out..
Thanks a lot

btw     `"pug": "2.0.4"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a recycled answer but can you just use the whitespace property in CSS?

```
  p(style='white-space:pre')
    | Pahoittelemme, tapahtui tekninen virhe, josta automaattinen palautuminen ei ollut mahdollista
    br
    | voit ilmoita virheestä xxxx, tai yritä hetken kuluttua uudestaan.
    br
    | Kiitos.
```